# How to get text from commandline with python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I need to read out the text from a cmd prompt window (which updates every second) in my Python program. I'm using Windows 7. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

edit:

I didn’t explain it very well.
The cmd prompt is already open and I need to read out everything it prints.
I have to "link" my Python program to the command prompt.

Comment: Google "python input" ?

Comment: Do you mean you need to scrap the window's text (actually, any window's text) by running a python script?

Comment: Yeah, thats what i need to do

Comment: In windows to access the terminal you specific the file "CON" or "CON:" (linux equivalent of /dev/tty). I would try something like `while True: print(open("CON:").read())`

Comment: that did not work for me =(

Comment: What is running in the command window? If your Python program can run (whatever it is) as a subprocess, it would be much easier to grab the output text.

Answer (score 1):

You should read :[module-subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **sys.argv** ?.

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

The first argument will be your file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `subprocess.check_output()`

```
import subprocess
command = "dir"
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, text=True)
print(output)
```

Don't forget to add `shell=True` and `text=True` argument